# recursion working in python code to find max

Tags: python, list, recursion

I am new to the concept of recursion trying to figure how the following code is working

```
def Max(list):
    if len(list) == 1:
        return list[0]
    else:
        m = Max(list[1:])
        return m if m > list[0] else list[0]

def main():
    list = eval(raw_input(" please enter a list of numbers: "))
    print("the largest number is: ", Max(list))


    main()
```

I am having the following doubts while looking at the code

1) How the slicing is working here without giving  the slice where it should end [0:9](in these manner how the list is being sliced)

2)When will the  **return m if m > list[0] else list[0]**statement will be called (i am thinking it won't be called because before return we will be calling the function several times )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to recursion - it's difficult to understand, but it has a strange kind of elegance/beauty to it.

It usually helps me to think about this with an example.

Let's assume this list: `1, 2, 3`

We're going to run `Max([1,2,3])`

1. The length of the list is 3, so we jump to the else-part
2. We run `Max([2,3])` and save the result to `m` (Recursion #1)

   1. The length of `[2,3]` is != 0, we go to else
   2. We run `Max([3])` and save the result to `m` (Recursion #2)

      1. The length of `[3]` is == 1
      2. We return index 0, which is `3` (End of Recursion #2)
   3. We get a value of `3` for `m`
   4. Now we get to the statement `return m if m > list[0] else list[0]`
   5. Recap: `m = 3` and `list=[2,3]`
   6. `m > list[0]` so we return `m=3` (End of Recursion #1)
3. Recap time again: `m=3` and `list=[1,2,3]`
4. `m > list[0]` so we return `m=3`

**The result of `Max([1,2,3])` is `3`.**

Note that each call to `Max` in the code creates *"new"* variables for `m` and `list` that are only visible inside of that function. The inner `Max` doesn't know about `m` and `list` of the outer `Max` and vice versa.

The calls flow looks like this:

```
+----------------+
|   Max([1,2,3]  | +----+
+------^---------+      | Step 1
       |                |
Step 4 |       +--------v------+
       +-------+   Max([2,3])  +---+
   return 3    +---^-----------+   | Step 2
                   |               |
           Step 3  |     +---------v-----+
                   +-----+   Max([3])    |
             return 3    +---------------+
```

**To address 1):**

When we slice using [n:] this means: start at index `n` and take the rest of the list.

**To address 2):**

After we get out of the recursion, see the example above.

---

**Further Reading**

- [Analogy for teaching recursion](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/17/analogy-for-teaching-recursion) over on CS Educators

---

Edit in response to your comment

To help you understand the line `return m if m > list[0] else list[0]` I suggest you try to mentally keep track of the state before the recursive call and after the recursive call.

The idea of this `Max` implementation is this: Recursively go to the last element in the list, then take that and check it against the second-to-last element if the last is larger keep that, otherwise keep the second-to-last.

If your list looked like this `[1,6,3,5,4,2]`, the levels of recursion would return this:

The first number in the bracket is `m` and the second is the value of `list[0]`

- 2 (N/A, 2)
- 4 (2, 4)
- 5 (4, 5)
- 5 (5, 3)
- 6 (5, 6)
- 6 (6, 1)

Ultimately  the function begins at the end of the list, takes the last value as the initial value and moving to the beginning, while always keeping the larger value which results in the largest value being returned.

(This is difficult to put into writing, hopefully you'll understand)

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation and work ,

But how the list value is being stored  (such as [2,3,] and 1,2,3 i am thinking code will get terminated once function call is finshed) do it create any memory space (if it creates any memory space when will it know to clear the memory space for example for much time will it store the list)

Comment: Each call to `Max` sort of creates *new* variables that are called `m` and `list` that exist within the scope of that call. So the "inner" `Max` doesn't know about the values of the "outer" `Max` and vice versa.

Comment: so finally i am thinking  the result of the last execution  passes the result to the last next execution in these manner the execution takes place(correct me if i am wrong)

Comment: Thanks a lot for patience and explanation

Comment: Not sure if understand your thought, but I tried to visualize it above. Think of it like opening one of those russian dolls and closing them.

Comment: Recursion is tough to wrap your head around, but really cool (not computationally efficient though) - glad I could help.

Comment: can you explain these line [return m if m > list[0] else list[0]] (i am thinking m will check the list index 0  if m is greater it will return m  else will it return list[0] to m?)

Comment: I tried adding further explanations - if this doesn't help, please try to run the algorithm on paper a few times until it "clicks", that usually works for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55113683/how-the-return-is-working-in-recursion-with-reference-to-the-following-code 
can you solve the above link for me

Answer (score 0):

1. This is a normal way of slicing. `[1:]` means from the first element until the end.
2. The function is recursive. So if you have a list of elements `[4,3]`, it

1) takes the `else` branch of the if statement two times, computes `[4,3][1:]` as [3] and calls `Max([3])`).

2) The list in the second stage of the recursion has length of 1, so it takes the first branch of the if-statement and returns 3 as elements.

3) we are back in the first call, where we compare the first element list[0]=4 with the result m=3 and get the bigger of them as return value.